# Swift 5: JSON from Alamofiire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a class that contains some Alamofire code to get JSON from a server, convert it into a pre-defined model and then return that model as an array.

Here is the code

```
func GetLights(completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<[LightList]>) -> Void) -> Alamofire.DataRequest {
    return AF.request(APIString + "/lights").responseJSON { response in
        let LightListResponse = response.flatMap { json in
            try JSONDecoder().decode([LightList].self, from: response.data!)
        }

        completionHandler(LightListResponse)
    }
}

func GetLightList() {
    GetLights { response in
        if let lights = response.value {
            print(lights)
        }
    }
}
```

I can breakpoint through to the JSONDecoder and see the json via debug but the print line at the end prints nothing, it doesn't even hit a breakpoint.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I think I'm using the completion handler correctly?

I am calling the GetLightList via a SwiftUI file like so:

```
func InitList() {
    let requests = Requests()

    requests.GetLightList()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this using `responseJSON`, as that method has already parsed the JSON using `JSONSerialization` and made it available to you as part of the response. Instead, you should use `responseDecodable`, since you already have a `Decodable` type.

```swift
return AF.request(apiString + "/lights").responseDecodable(of: [LightList].self) { response in
    completionHandler(response)
}
```

However, it's often best not to expose the `DataResponse` type produced by Alamofire but instead use the `Result` from the response in your completion handler.

Additionally, updating your styling to match Swift's recommended style will help you write consistent code. Namely, methods and variable names should start with a lowercase letter to separate them from type declarations. You can see this in your code samples where it thinks things like "APIString" are types and not variables.

Finally, it's often helpful to not overload `get` as a method prefix. For network calls I like using `fetch` when requesting a resource. e.g. `fetchLights`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this tonight! I'll take your best practices to mind

Comment: In the official documentation they used HTTPBinResponse.self for the of parameter but I didn't know what to use if the JSON was an array. Your answer helped me, thx.